# Google Scripts / Sheets: How do I hide 3 cells based on the value of one cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As a non-developer, could anyone advise on a script I could use to hide 3 cells based on what one cell says? Please see the sample spreadsheet [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PMktieozNgHQLPkwI_GrxUdHXeIteKEFN-3hnXHuugM/edit?usp=sharing) I would like to hide the 3 blue cells if the formula used throws out "TRUE", otherwise if it has a normal value, I would like the cells to remain as I have formatted them. Any advice would be appreciated. I do have VBA experience but seem a bit slow to catch onto Google Scripts.
(Any recommendations on courses I could take?)

Thank you so much for all the great advice on here! Extremely helpful to a newbie like me.

[image: Spreadsheet cells]

Comment: Do you mean hide rows?  There is no way to hide cells and leave other cells in that row visible.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, I really wanted to do cells. But that explains why I couldn't find anything about hiding cells anywhere. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: I think I'm just going to make a copy and then delete the cells instead of hiding them. Or open to any other suggestions?

Comment: What you could do is have a duplicate sheet with all the values.  If the master sheet is true copy the values to the duplicate and then delete the contents of the master sheet cells.  If false recover the values from the duplication.  Not sure how dynamic your spreadsheet is.  This could be done through an onEdit(e) trigger.

Comment: I'm going to do that. Thank you so much for the advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [TheWizEd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656739/thewized) mentioned there is no way to hide cells and leave other cells in the same row at the same time, however using the solution with two sheets you could try something as this [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzPBFq090dA2biq9p3BdTrK7CMsjSkLFrV2-BIc8htI/edit?usp=sharing) that I made.

Following the logic that depending on the value of a certain cell the row will hide you can try to apply it to your specific scenario. In my case I used a `Yes/No` value to hide an entire row:

[image]

When selecting `Yes` the row in `Sheet2` will hide.

This is the script used:

```
var sheet = "Sheet1";
var editingsheet = "Sheet2";
var val = "Yes";
var column = 3;
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editingss = ss.getSheetByName(editingsheet);

  if(sheet == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
    var cellnotation = cell.getA1Notation();
    var cvalue = cell.getValue();

    if(cell.getColumn() == column){
      if(cvalue == val){
        var range = editingss.getRange(cellnotation);
        editingss.hideRow(range);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the result that I get when selecting `Yes` on Funny item 1 and 12:

[image]